# TempFileCollection "extra" files

Tags: .net

I have been trying to understand some third party code we use (and fortunately have the source for) and am unclear on their use of TempFileCollection (hereafter, TFC) objects.

If one creates such an object with a directory thus and so as BasePath, then creates a file within that directory by whatever means, does disposing the TFC delete the file within that directory? Or does the file have to be explicitly added to the TFC object with the AddFile and related methods for this behaviour to happen?

Comment: ... ... make a console app, do it, then see what happens?  A two second peek at the finalize method says `Attempts to delete the temporary files before this object is reclaimed by garbage collection. (Overrides Object.Finalize().)` Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for answering. No, it doesn't quite answer it because "the temporary files" is precisely what is vague. I'll run the experiment, but people's previous experience can help with these obscure matters too.

Comment: Well, anything you put in it is a temporary file, isn't it?  Why call it a TempFileCollection otherwise?  From the docs, it looks like you can mark files in the collection as not to be deleted as well, so it seems that's the point of it.

Comment: I've run the experiment, but I have no idea if this is the expected behaviour in .NET or whether or not it is a bug there. In any case the result is fairly clear. If one uses AddFile to add a temporary file to the TFC, it gets deleted at process termination time (which I take it is the GC non-determinism). If one does not, but simply writes to the temp directory created by the TFC, the file *stays*. This is exactly what the third party code does. However, that does not tell us if the third party code is wrong or whether the .NET class itself is out of spec (with regards to what?)